# How can I make the following action method thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, thread-safety

The following two links access the same action method:

`http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/accessories/podmount` and `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`

I use `Request.Url.Host` to determine the brand of products I want to return from a database.  When I access `http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/accessories/podmount` first, `Request.Url.Host` contains the value `stage.bullydog.com`, but if I then go to `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`, `Request.Url.Host` may contain `stage.sctflash.com` or it may contain `stage.bullydog.com`.

The action method that is called is:

```
public ActionResult GetAccessoriesByType(RenderModel model, string id)
    {
        Common _common = new Common();
        string brand = Request.Url != null ? _common.GetProductBrand() : BrandType.SCT;

        var productSearchResultsModel = new ProductSearchResultsModel
        {
            Accessories = _accessoryRepository.GetAccessoriesByType(id, brand)
        };

        return View("~/Views/accessories.cshtml", productSearchResultsModel);
    }
```

The code that gets the brand is:

```
public class Common
{
    public string GetProductBrand()
    {
        var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

        if (host.Contains("sctflash"))
            return BrandType.SCT;

        if (host.Contains("bigrig") || host.Contains("bigrigs"))
            return BrandType.BigRig;

        if (host.Contains("bullydog"))
            return BrandType.BullyDog;

        return BrandType.SCT;
    }
}
```

How can I ensure the `Request.Url.Host` contains the proper host when the same action method is accessed from two different hosts?

You can see this in action if you go to `http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/accessories/podmount` and then go to `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount` and refresh either one, the logo should change which means that the value returned by `Request.Url.Host` was incorrect.

Also, can GetProductBrand be static and still be thread-safe in this case?

Comment: They're two requests right? So they should be unique. I don't see any statics or anything that says it isn't thread safe.

Comment: @TyCobb - The 2 urls call the same controller/action method.  I just can't figure out why one url returns the url of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why accessing another website was bringing back the one websites content and the `Request.Url.Host` had the other websites information was because I had declared `OutPutCache[Duration=60]` at the top of my controller.  If I waited 60 seconds and then refreshed, the correct data for each website would return.  Once I removed this from the controller, everything worked as expected.